# WinJS Virtualized Data Source + nested asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, winjs

Hi i'm relatively new to JavaScript and i'm working on a winjs app project where i want to use the [Bing image search data source example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en_us/library/windows/apps/hh770849.aspx) in my project to virtualize the datasource of a listview.

My problem is understanding how the asynchronous functions work together and how to implement an async xhr request within the existing one.

Currently i'm using a synchronous request but i would like to change that into a asynchronous one.

This is my data adapter:

```
(function () {

    var xxxDataAdapter = WinJS.Class.define(
        function (devkey, query, delay) {
            this._minPageSize = 2;
            this._maxPageSize = 5;
            this._maxCount = 50;
            this._devkey = devkey;
            this._query = query;
            this._delay = 0;
        },

        {
            getCount: function () {
                var that = this;

                var requestStr = 'http://xxx/' + that._query;

                return WinJS.xhr({ url: requestStr, type: "GET", /*user: "foo", password: that._devkey,*/ }).then(

                    function (request) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                        if (typeof obj.error === "undefined") {
                            var count = obj.length;
                            if (count === 0) { console.log("The search returned 0 results.", "sample", "error"); }
                            return count;
                        } else {
                            console.log("Error fetching results from API", "sample", "error");
                            return 0;
                        }
                    },
                    function (request) {
                        if (request && request.name === "Canceled") {
                            return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(request);
                        } else {
                            if (request.status === 401) {
                                console.log(request.statusText, "sample", "error");
                            } else {
                                console.log("Error fetching data from the service. " + request.responseText, "sample", "error");
                            }

                            return 0;
                        }
                    });
            },

            itemsFromIndex: function (requestIndex, countBefore, countAfter)
            {
                var that = this;
                if (requestIndex >= that._maxCount) {
                    return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(new WinJS.ErrorFromName(WinJS.UI.FetchError.doesNotExist));
                }

                var fetchSize, fetchIndex;
                if (countBefore > countAfter) {
                    //Limit the overlap
                    countAfter = Math.min(countAfter, 0);
                    //Bound the request size based on the minimum and maximum sizes
                    var fetchBefore = Math.max(Math.min(countBefore, that._maxPageSize - (countAfter + 1)), that._minPageSize - (countAfter + 1));
                    fetchSize = fetchBefore + countAfter + 1;
                    fetchIndex = requestIndex - fetchBefore;
                } else {
                    countBefore = Math.min(countBefore, 10);
                    var fetchAfter = Math.max(Math.min(countAfter, that._maxPageSize - (countBefore + 1)), that._minPageSize - (countBefore + 1));
                    fetchSize = countBefore + fetchAfter + 1;
                    fetchIndex = requestIndex - countBefore;
                }

                var requestStr = 'http://xxx/' + that._query;

                return WinJS.xhr({ url: requestStr, type: "GET", /*user: "foo", password: that._devkey,*/ }).then(

                    function (request)
                    {
                        var results = [], count;

                        var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                        if (typeof obj.error === "undefined")
                        {
                            var items = obj;

                            for (var i = 0, itemsLength = items.length; i < itemsLength; i++)
                            {
                                var dataItem = items[i];

                                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                // false =  synchronous
                                req.open("get", "http://xxxxx/" + dataItem.id, false);
                                req.send();

                                var jobj = JSON.parse(req.response);
                                if (typeof jobj.error === "undefined")
                                {
                                    results.push({
                                        key: (fetchIndex + i).toString(),
                                        data: {
                                            title: jobj.name.normal,
                                            date: Date.jsonFormat(dataItem.calculatedAt, "Do, MMM HH:mm Z"),
                                            result: "",
                                            status: "",
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            return {
                                items: results, // The array of items
                                offset: requestIndex - fetchIndex, // The offset into the array for the requested item
                            };

                        } else {
                            console.log(request.statusText, "sample", "error");
                            return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(new WinJS.ErrorFromName(WinJS.UI.FetchError.doesNotExist));
                        }
                    },

                    function (request)
                    {
                        if (request.status === 401) {
                            console.log(request.statusText, "sample", "error");
                        } else {
                            console.log("Error fetching data from the service. " + request.responseText, "sample", "error");
                        }
                        return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(new WinJS.ErrorFromName(WinJS.UI.FetchError.noResponse));
                    }
                );
            }
        });

    WinJS.Namespace.define("xxx", {
        datasource: WinJS.Class.derive(WinJS.UI.VirtualizedDataSource, function (devkey, query, delay) {
            this._baseDataSourceConstructor(new xxxDataAdapter(devkey, query, delay));
        })
    });

})();
```

And this is the synchronous request i would like to change to an asynchronous one:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
// false =  synchronous
req.open("get", "http://xxxxx/" + dataItem.id, false);
req.send();
```

Comment: for the later code you can use `WinJS.xhr()` function instead of XMLHttpRequest - the function returns a promise. for detailed understanding of promises in winjs lib, msdn documentation of winjs.promise is good starting point.

Comment: @Sushil i couldn't find an example where a nested asynchron request is executed depending on results of a parent asynchron request using promises... maybe you can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i came up with. Map the json objects received asynchronously and make another asynchronous call for each object to get additional data. Then the nested async calls are joined and returned when all are finished.

```
    return WinJS.xhr({ url: 'http://xxx=' + that._query }).then(function (request) {

        var results = [];

        var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        var xhrs = obj.map(function (dataItem, index) {

            return WinJS.xhr({ url: 'http://xxxx' + dataItem.attrx }).then(

                function completed(nestedRequest) {

                    var xxJobj = JSON.parse(nestedRequest.responseText);

                    var dataObj = {};
                    dataObj.title = xxJobj.name;
                    dataObj.date = Date.jsonFormat(dataItem.attrtrxx, "Do, MMM HH:mm Z");
                    dataObj.result = "open";
                    dataObj.status = "foo";

                    if (dataItem.xx.hasOwnProperty("attrx5")) {
                        dataObj.opponent = dataItem.attrx4;
                    } else {
                        dataObj.opponent = dataItem.attrx3;
                    }

                    dataObj.page_title = "xXx";
                    dataObj.match_id = dataItem.id;
                    dataObj.type = "largeListIconTextItem";
                    dataObj.bg_image = "http://xxx/" + xxJobj.attrx2 + "-portrait.jpg";

                    results.push({
                        key: (fetchIndex + index).toString(),
                        data: dataObj
                    });

                },

                function (err) {
                    console.log(err.status);
                    console.log(err.responseText);
                }
            );
        });

        return WinJS.Promise.join(xhrs).then(

            function (promises) {
                return {
                    items: results, // The array of items
                    offset: requestIndex - fetchIndex, // The offset into the array for the requested item
                };
            },

            function (err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        );

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `then` function to chain promises. In your scenario, then function need to simple have a if statement.

```
return WinJS.xhr(params).then(function (req) 
{
    if (..)
        return WinJS.xhr(params2);
    else
        return; // then function ensures wrapping your sync result in a completed promise
}, function onerror(e) 
{
    // todo - error handling code e.g. showing a message box based on your app requirement
});
```